# Url for adding a survey in a sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013

I have to provide a link for admin user to add a survey to the list. This applictaion is migrated from 2007. In 2013, since its an app, can we use url like this.

`Site/_layouts/15/new.aspx?FeatureId=%7B00bfea71%2Deb8a%2D40b1%2D80c7%2D506be7590102%7D&ListTemplate=102`

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, normal lists are also called "apps" in SharePoint 2013. Direct links to new list item form work the same way, although you need to verify the link URL, as they might not be 100% identical with 2007.